# Getting Google User ID in Node.js in Firebase Functions for Assistant App

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm getting started with Google Cloud Platform.

I'm developing an Android App that will collect information and store it in a Firebase App. The idea is that a Google Assistant function can query this information and read it back- eg

> OK Google, Talk To Simons App, Tell me the last time XYZ was done

The problem I've got however, is to get this being multi user.

I've got the Android App collecting data and putting it into the cloud. I'm using the `FirebaseUser` and using `getUid()` in the Android app to get a unique id which is a 28 character string like `uVHkia8RRgWD8GGPVvW4AUDUK2`.

I've setup Actions on Google, got it hooked into API.AI with Web Fulfilment and got Node.js working in firebase functions.

Unfortunately, the `UserID` I get back looks more like:`HTge48H0CF2FC5jJQCigFBc-UCQ`

The problem is that this `UserID` is not the same as the `UserUID` I got from Filebase User.

Im using

```
let ApiAiApp = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiApp;
const app = new ApiAiApp({request: request, response: response});
```

and

```
const userId = app.getUser().userId;
```

What am I missing? I see references to OAuth2, Account Linking etc. I'm not entirely sure what to do at this point. All I need to do at the moment, is get the `User UID` like I get from `FirebaseUser.getUID()` in order to look the data up in the Firebase Database.

I think the rest should be straight forward.

There's loads of documentation on linking to Firebase from the Assistant, but very little on actually authenticating. So far I've not setup an flows, like Authorization Code Flows, Implicit Flows, or set a username/password against API.AI and the Fulfilment option. Quite frankly Im not sure what needs to go where at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user provided by `app.getUser().userId` is designed as a [persistent anonymous identifier](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info#anonymous_user_identity). It is roughly the equivalent of a cookie that one sets in a web server - you can use it to determine if you've seen this user before, and what else they've done in your Action, but it does not inheriently relate to any outside account.

Unfortunately, the best solution you have at this point is to use [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking) which requires you to setup an OAuth2 server. As part of this setup, you will need to create three components:

1. A login web page for your service. You'll provide the URL for this page to Google as part of Account Linking. When the user accesses your Action, and your action indicates they need to log in, they'll be redirected to this URL on their mobile device. On this page the user will log in - once logged in, you now know their Firebase ID and will create an *auth code* for this user. You'll then redirect them back to a different URL and pass this auth code (along with some other info) as a parameter.
2. A token exchange endpoint. Google will call this URL with the auth code above. You'll verify this code, determine who the user is, and send back a unique *access token*. (You'll also send back a *refresh token* that Google will use in the same way to get an updated access token.)
3. An auth token handler in your webhook. When API.AI calls your webhook, it will include the access token as one of the fields in the request. You can use this access token to get the Firebase ID for the user.

One thing to note for the auth code, the access token, and the refresh token is that you'll need to have some way to map from these codes/tokens to the Firebase ID. There are two good ways to do this:

1. The code/token can be a JSON Web Token (JWT). This takes the Firebase ID, and other information you wish to retain about the user, and puts it in a standard format. It then creates a cryptographic signature, to make sure it hasn't been tampered with, and encodes it in a standard format. When you need to determine the ID from the JWT, you can decode it, verify the signature is valid, and read the value.
2. Generate a random string and store this in your database against the Firebase ID. When you get the token, you can then look up in your database the ID that this string was assigned to.

There are many additional details about an OAuth implementation and about each of these steps. See https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow for more details.

Comment: Thanks Prisoner. This sort of makes sense. I gather the OAuth2 server would be the bit that ties the Android App and the Google Assistant together. At the time of logging on via Android however, I have no reference to the Persistent Anonymous Identifier, and when I have the Identifier in Firebase, I don't have access to the Uid. So how to glue this together?

Comment: The glue is done because when they try to link accounts in the Assistant, they're redirected to an oauth login page. I've updated the answer to try and clarify this a bit further.

Comment: Thanks. I may have misinterpreted Google OAuth. I didn't intend to maintain my own backend authentication. I wanted to integrate to Google on the phone and home and gain a corresponding key to link to data in firebase. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/ looks simple from Android - I don't need to worry about OAuth here. I thought this would be the same on Google Home. That's annoying that I have to setup OAuth2, even more annoying that I can't just set a service up in Google to do it all automatically!

Comment: Agreed that it is annoying. Hopefully they will come up with more a more integrated and streamlined method soon!

Comment: Next bit... I've got my certificate for HTTPS, setup an Auth and a Token endpoint so user can login. Tested in the Playground. How does Firebase Functions (that Im using for Actions on Google) actually get the firebase user Id?